# Qt: Convertion of a QString from utf16 to utf8

Tags: qt, utf-8, utf-16, qstring

i'm trying to convert some data get from a txt file coded in utf16 to utf8 by using Qt. Could someone help in this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `const std::string utf8there = QString( "text" ).toStdString();`

Comment: `QString` has a [`toUtf8`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8) function. Please at least do a cursory search of the documentation before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QString` provides methods to [import from UTF-16](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf16) and [export to UTF-8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toUtf8), and vice versa of course, and many others. The `QByteArray` objects used for input/output of these methods are best handled by using [`QFile`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html).

You should be able to find your way from there; if you have other problems with using this facilities you're supposed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get appropriate help.

Comment: @MarcoFerrara You're welcome :-) Please don't forget to mark the question as answered when it is solved.

Comment: This is not an answer. There are a LOT of topics to cover in uhf8 and utf16.

Comment: What do you mean by "and vice versa"? As far as I can see there is no `toUtf16` method.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Know your Qt conventions: No `to`prefix for getters, and linked from the related methods in the doc:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#utf16

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringconverter.html

> The QStringConverter class is a base class for the [QStringEncoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringencoder.html) and
> [QStringDecoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringdecoder.html) classes that help with converting between different
> text encodings. [QStringDecoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringdecoder.html) can decode a string from an encoded
> representation into UTF-16, the format Qt uses internally.
> [QStringEncoder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringencoder.html) does the opposite operation, encoding UTF-16 encoded
> data (usually in the form of a [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html)) to the requested encoding.